# What Rails Active Record Migration datatype to use for time duration of a contract?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to capture the term of a contract in the database of my application.  I am using postgres with rails 3.  The term is the duration of the contract.  Some examples of inputs could be 5 years, 3 and a half years, or 2 years 3 months.  I generally want to be able to capture the duration in years and months.  What datatype should I use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to capture only the months (as an integer), or have 2 separate fields.  One each for years and months.  You could have months implemented as a drop down menu so that only 0 through 11 are acceptable values.

The last option is to use datetime, which is far more precise than what you want, so I wouldn't recommend it for this.

Comment: datetime isn't an interval. if you use datetime, you'd need to have another field to create the range of time.

Answer (score 4):

Postgresql supports an `interval` data type.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I can't see `intervals` in there anywhere... An `interval` is a value like `3 days` but that seems to be all about `ranges` (values like `from 2 days ago until tomorrow`).

Comment: I'm not sure how this works with ActiveRecord, but this is how it's handled in postgresql: https://gist.github.com/joevandyk/d14fd860f4270a5cc17d

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7518 is a bug about the interval support in ActiveRecord.. maybe that means it will be supported in version 4.

Comment: That bug says interval maps to string in rails (not new to Rails 4). I don't count that as proper support! Personally, I'd use an integer field for the number of minutes /months and then return a time length from the accessor in the model.

Answer (score 2):

I would use two datetime attributes, start_date and end_date,  that way you can decide later how to express the term of the contract any way you want, years/months, days, minutes, seconds,  whatever you want.

You could define a pseudo attribute called term, i.e.

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  def term
    return self.end_date - self.start_date
  end
end
```

term would in seconds,  you could do some simple math and return months, years and months, etc. You could also use DateHelper,  i.e.

```
distance_of_time_in_words(@contract.start_date,@contract.end_date)
```

will print an approximation string like '1 year' or '3 years', 'about 1 year', etc.